# Numerical Analysis approximating equilibrium points

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the differential equations:

$\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}=x_1(t)(4-0.33x_1(t)-0.42x_2(t))$

$\frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}=x_2(t)(2-0.25x_1(t)-0.12x_2(t))$

I need to approximate the equilibrium points accurately to the nearest individual using numerical methods so when:

$\frac{dx_1(t)}{dt}=0$  $\frac{dx_2(t)}{dt}=0$

I'm not sure which method to use (Euler, Fixed-point iteration, Jacobian,..)
I computed the Jacobian Matrix but i dont know if that helps.

Comment: What if i found the inverse of the Jacobian and then use Newtons method with an initial approximation?

Comment: ok thanks, but what would i use as initial values?

Comment: I think i have to do it numerically. And i tried plotting the graph but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Thanks very much, the reason this one is easy to do by hand is because i changed the coefficients from the one i'm doing.

Comment: is it possible to eliminate each term then using fixed-point iteration to find the root?

Comment: Ok i'll give it a go thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the equilibrium points, you can basically solve this problem by hand. Note that there is an obvious solution $x_1 = x_2 = 0$. Alternatively, you can try to set one of $x_1$ or $x_2$ to zero. When $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 20$, and when $x_2 = 0$, $x_1 = 10$. Another solution is setting the quantities in the parentheses equal to zero, or in other words solve
$$ 3-0.3x_1 - 0.4x_2 = 0 $$
$$ 2-0.2x_1 - 0.1x_2 = 0 $$
which requires solving a $2\times2$ linear system, giving $x_1 = 10$, $x_2 = 0$, which is the same as the previous answer.